# How to bind slot with v-bind for url attribute?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to pass attributes from component to slot?

This is in component

```
<navigation-link url="/profile">
  Your Profile
</navigation-link>
```

Then in the template I want to use url

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      v-bind:href="url"
      class="nav-link">
      <slot></slot>
    </a>
    <span class="active></span>
  <div>
</template>
```

according to docs this should work, but instead I get error: `Property or method "url" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put the text "Your Profile" in `<slot></slot>`

So, for this, you need to do this.

```
<navigation-link url="/profile">
   <template slot="text">
      Your Profile
   </template>
</navigation-link>
```

And in the component, name the slot like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a
      v-bind:href="url"
      class="nav-link">
      <slot name="text" />
    </a>
    <span class="active></span>
  <div>
</template>
```

Probably, this work.

**EDIT:**

> according to docs this should work, but instead I get error: Property or method "url" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

That is because, you are not declaring url in the component, you probably need to put

```
props: ['url'],
data() {
 return {
    propUrl: this.url
  }
}
```

and in the template use this.propUrl

Regards

Comment: I am trying to do something as shown in this [example](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content)

Comment: Hi!, please check the EDIT, the tutorial is for use slot and just take for granted some thinks, please check this [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Comment: In this case I needed only to add props: ['url'], return in data was not required.